# Running time of this pseudocode algorithms

Tags: algorithm, runtime, quicksort, mergesort

What would be the running time of the following algorithm:

```
algo1(int n){
   i = n*n;
   while(i > 1){
      i = i/2;
   }
}
```

Is it correct to say that the while loop will execute log(n^2) times, which is equivalent to 2log(n), and therefore the running time would be theta(logn)

Now, look at this second algorithm:

```
algo2(int A[0...n-1], int n){
   mergeSort(A, 0, n-1);
   quickSort(A, 0, n-1);
}
```

mergeSort will execute run in time O(nlog(n)). Assuming quickSort always chooses as pivot the element at the right end of the array, then the running time of quicksort will be the worst case scenario O(n^2). So the runtime would be theta(n^2)?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: [Yes, you are correct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202122/how-should-we-handle-am-i-correct-questions-when-theyre-correct). But you shouldn't really be asking two different questions in one.

Comment: Quicksort is O(n^2) in the worst case, O(n log(n)) in the average case.

Comment: @LorenPechtel But if you sort using merge-sort first, and then always pick the first or last element as the pivot, you'll get O(n^2).